# What's the fastest dinosaur? and what properties make it so fast?

Tags: ornithology, palaeontology, dinosaurs

I am a new user.

I was curious about the fastest dinosaur that existed during the Mezozoic era.
However as I researched, via Google, I was unable to find any precise information as few of them gave the title to, Troodon, other to Velociraptor, others refer to NanoTyrannosaurus. (According to my personal research, I find 3 dinos in the first place since the run at the same speed of approximately 80 kmph, Nano T-Rex, Troodon and Gallimimus as suggested in the comments, I don't think Velociraptor is classified as the fastest because they run at almost half the speed as the fastest ones. I was looking whether is there any better estimate of their speeds which keeps only 1 at the top)

So who is actually the fastest dino (including both  Saurischia and Ornithischia dinosaurs i.e regardless of hip structure. Also I want to know whether the fastest ones are generally bipedal or quadrupedal ,Probably Bipedal because the fastest dinos fall under the category of theropods?)?

Thanks!

Comment: On our current Earth, birds of prey stooping can reach up to 200 mph/320 Kph. We can measure that with scientific instruments as it happens. What kind of an answer are you looking for considering the time elapsed since any of these creatures were around? Also consider, estimates vary and experts disagree on what might have been possible.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. Thanks for telling me about that. I think that There should be some genes, that make a theropod so fast, like myostatin inhibits muscle growth, there must be some ancestor whose mutation caused the agility of theropods in the gene pool. I would like to know about that ancestor of current living dinosaurs a.k.a birds.

Comment: You should note that the earliest/oldest DNA we have been able to recover is about 2.4 million years old and is not from fossils, but frozen in permafrost. Dinosaurs became extinct 65 million years ago and all the remains we have are fossilized, which does not preserve DNA, not even promising amber samples (*a la* Jurassic Park) have been shown to contain DNA that is older than a few thousand years. This means no chance of working out genes!

Comment: @bob1 Thank you for telling me that. But I have a question: Would we able to study the fast dinosaurs by studying the fossils, maybe we have found, similar hip, leg structure for the fastest ones? Then perhaps we could trace the earliest dating source and compare living specimen, birds to find the gene?

Comment: Potentially yes, but it would take lots of modeling of locomotion of each species to work out speeds - paleontologists can't even agree on whether T-rex was an active hunter and speed or if it was a scavenger and slow walker, and that's one of the more studied species.

Comment: Ichnology, (study of dinosaur traces e.g. [footprints](https://igws.indiana.edu/outreach/additional/activities/DinoMeasurements.pdf)) is one of the things being explored with technology, but some limitations are the few samples available compared with the totality of extinct life, and the uncertainty of CG models built on fuzzy data.

Comment: @bob1 So according to our current technological capabilities, we won't be able to figure out the speed of the fastest dinos? Will we able to estimate it in the near future?

Comment: We can refine the techniques we use to study the currently available data including comparisons to extant species, but unless we get a time machine to get first-hand data, we're still working with speculative (but informed) models based on a limited data set.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. Thank you for telling me that. So was ichology performed on theropods, and related species?

Comment: It's like detective work of a crime that happened hundreds of years ago and without any witnesses when the evidence has been trampled by elephants. We work with the traces available and it's the best educated guesses as to what creatures they belonged to. Footprints *seem* to match what we know of fossils - but it's not as if they conveniently own-up to who's footprint belongs to which species. That's why there's so much varying opinion between experts, the data is, as I said, fuzzy.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. Ok, Thanks for letting me know that. So, because of our technological capabilities we won't be able to find the neither the gene nor the ancestor who caused the mutation . Please don't mind my questions since I am a newbie in this field (I have just 1 last doubt), but can we estimate it using osteology, and skeletal analysis from their fossils just how we found for some theropods like troodon and Nano-TRex?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147834/discussion-between-arjun-and-jiminy-cricket).

Comment: There's an interesting paper that might help you get an idea of the state of the art re genetic paleobiology: [Ancient DNA and paleogenetics: risks and potentiality](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8167392/). It might help give you an idea of the limitations that are being worked with - notice that in the long-term, the DNA degrades by itself from thermal noise. Thermodynamics puts a limit on how long it survives, the length of fragments limits the ability of reassembly on a computer. This isn't the place for discussions (however interesting), but so dig into the topic.

Comment: question for a paleontology forum. gallimimus was allegedly about 80kph.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. Thanks. The paper is quite interesting, I will read it to get to know more about it

Comment: With many competing ways of reconstructing and estimating speed, combined with how many dinosaurs just have not been studied in this way this is unanswerable.